# Trigger functionality doesn't work as expected for History insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that contains 2 main functions 
The first function works good witch it upgrade `AccountType`, and the other one not stable witch insert a `history` for this operation in another Table--> **AccountTypeMonior**,

```
Create  TRIGGER [dbo].[CustomerAccountUpgrade]
ON [dbo].[Customer]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

Declare 
        @None nvarchar(10) = 'None',
        @Standard nvarchar(10) = 'Standard',
        @Basic nvarchar(10) ='Basic',
        @Classic nvarchar(10) ='Classic',
        @Golden nvarchar(10) ='Golden',
        @Platinum nvarchar(10) = 'Platinum'



-- Regular Customers



BEGIN
   BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Customer 
    SET AccountTypeID =
     Case 
     When (i.TotalSales < 0)
     Then 0
      When (i.TotalSales = 0)
     Then 10
    When (i.TotalSales BETWEEN 1 AND 5000)
    Then 8 
    When (i.TotalSales BETWEEN 5000.01 AND 10000)
    Then 3
    When (i.TotalSales BETWEEN 10000.01 AND 20000)
    Then 4
    When (i.TotalSales > 20000)
    Then 5
    End

    FROM Inserted i  JOIN Deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID  -- use the primary key here
    WHERE d.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
            AND i.TotalSales != d.TotalSales  -- TotalSales was updated
            AND dbo.Customer.ID = i.ID   -- use the PK here
            AND i.CustomText1 != '1' AND i.CustomText2 ! = 'S' -- Not Assinged or Starhouse


            -- After Update Insert History to Account Type Monitor Table

                  INSERT INTO AccountTypeMonitor (ReferenceID,ReferenceType,OldSales,NewSales ,[Status] ,FromType,ToType,DateCreated )
                (SELECT
                i.ID,'AccountType',d.TotalSales,i.TotalSales,
                Case 

                When i.TotalSales > d.TotalSales Then 
                'Upgrade'
                When i.TotalSales < d.TotalSales  Then 
                'Downgrade'
                End 
                ,
                Case 
                When d.AccountTypeID = 0 
                Then @None
                When d.AccountTypeID = 3 
                Then @Classic
                When d.AccountTypeID =4 
                Then @Golden
                When d.AccountTypeID = 5
                Then @Platinum
                When d.AccountTypeID = 8
                Then @Basic
                End,
            Case 
             When (i.AccountTypeID = 0)
            Then @None
              When (i.AccountTypeID = 8)
             Then @Standard
            When (i.AccountTypeID = 8)
            Then @Basic 
            When (i.AccountTypeID = 3)
            Then @Classic
            When (i.AccountTypeID =4)
            Then @Golden
            When (i.AccountTypeID =5)
            Then @Platinum
            End,
                GetDate()


             FROM Inserted i  JOIN Deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID  -- use the primary key here
    WHERE d.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
            AND i.TotalSales != d.TotalSales  -- TotalSales was updated
            AND i.CustomText1 != '1' AND i.CustomText2 ! = 'S'
                )


   END
```

**Problem:**

when i make a transaction for the customer its upgrade well, but i set wrong data in the history table

like this

```
001  New Test Regular   0   11000   Upgrade Golden  Golden  2015-07-25 11:52:35.840 Account Number: 001 has Upgrade from Golden to Golden
```

**Which should be for example:**

> Basic To Golden

NOT

> Golden To Golden

Comment: You're updating the accounttypeid in the same trigger into the table? I have never tried what happens in that case but maybe that is the reason?

Comment: Don't even understand how you could get "Golden Golden" when your code has numbers for the new value so you could get "Golden 3" and Golden isn't even for the 11000 it should be Platinum, and your range is also buggy since it starts from 1000.01 instead of 10000.01

Comment: Yes you are right, because its not the original code, the other one is big, so i tried to make it simple, and i had to edit it manually on the page, so yes the range is buggy here, but not at the database

Comment: Well, test it without updating the table in the trigger and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: I Have replaced the code here with the original one from my database, i hope it could be easy to be understood.

Comment: Well have you tried what happens if you remove the update that could mess up the results?

Comment: Well, that Update part works as expected, the problem is with the insertion part, gives unexpected values in FromType and ToType

Comment: I still suspect that the update is the cause, so that the next select you're doing to inserted / deleted uses the values from the update inside the trigger and not the ones done by the user. Please try the trigger without the update.

Comment: Or actually, are you expecting the update in the beginning of the trigger to update the values into the inserted / deleted -columns later on?

Comment: Didn't test, but did the UPDATE Customer clause in the trigger recursively called itself after the UPDATE?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is with your AccountTypeID handling in the cursor vs the actual update clause you're running. Since you haven't included everything it's just a guess, but there's nothing else in your code you have included in the question that would explain it.

The solution is simple, remove the updating logic for AccountTypeID from the cursor, because that's the wrong way to do it anyhow. Drop the column from the table, and add a computed column to replace it:

```
alter table Customer add AccountTypeID as 
Case 
  When TotalSales < 0 Then 0
  When TotalSales = 0 Then 10
  When TotalSales <= 5000 Then 8 
  When TotalSales <= 10000 Then 3
  When TotalSales <= 20000 Then 4
  else 5
end
```

This way the data is up-to-date all the time without any triggers.

Comment: And if you want / need, you can also do the same thing with the account type explanations (Gold etc.) so you don't have to include that code in the trigger either